# gruntjs - command line arguments

Tags: gruntjs

Where can I get a handle for command line arguments?

eg `grunt dist --env=UAT`.  How do I get the value for `env`?

While I'm at it, how would I assign a default value to this if it's not set on the command line?

Comment: Do you need to handle arguments for a specific task?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `grunt.option()` or more specifically:

`var env = grunt.option('env') || 'default';`

to grab the `env` argument or default to the string `'default'` if the argument is not present.

Answer (score 0):

I find the handling of defaults in grunt to be sorely lacking. The method outlined above works, but it quickly gets tiresome when you have lots of options.

A little helper function can ease this:

```
function defaultOptions(options) {
  for(var key in options) {
    if(options.hasOwnProperty(key) && !grunt.option(key)) {
      grunt.option(key, options[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use like:

```
defaultOptions({
  env : "staging"
});
```

And at the CLI:

```
grunt // { env : "staging" }
grunt --env=UAT // { env : "UAT" }
```