# "grunt clock in" instead of "grunt clock --in" <-- Possible?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, command-line-interface

I'm looking around in the docs and I don't see this as being possible, but I would really like the api to my [grunt plugin](https://github.com/kentcdodds/grunt-clock) to be that much easier...

Comment: I know you can, but I've never done it that way... nothing in the docs about it? You can also do: `grunt clock:in` and get the extra bits through `this.args` in the handler function. I know, not the same.

Comment: Oh, actually, looks like you might have a duplicate... is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351932/gruntjs-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the task a single task and just use arguments:

```
grunt.registerTask('clock', function(which) {
  if (which === 'in') {
    /* clock in */
  } else if (which === 'out') {
    /* clock out */
  } else {
    grunt.log.error('I have no idea what that means');
  }
});
```

Then you can do `grunt clock:in` and `grunt clock:out`.

Otherwise if you absolutely prefer `grunt clock in` you would need to parse `process.argv` yourself.